# Understanding Redux's Reducer storing State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

While trying to understand the react/redux code in [gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth](https://github.com/gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth), I am confused about the state `state.auth.authenticated` returned by `mapStateToProps`.

For example, in the event where a user logins using the form,

[**/client/src/components/auth/signin.js**](https://github.com/gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth/blob/master/client/src/components/auth/signin.js#L20-L22)

```
class Signin extends Component {

    handleSubmit({email, password}) {
        this.props.signinUser({email, password});
    }
```

submitting the form causes the `signinUser` function to dispatch an action with `type: AUTH_USER`

[**/client/src/actions/index.js**](https://github.com/gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth/blob/master/client/src/actions/index.js#L5-L17)

```
export function signinUser({email, password}) {

  return function (dispatch) {

    // submit email and password to server
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/signin`, {email, password})
    request
      .then(response => {

        // -if request is good, we need to update state to indicate user is authenticated
        dispatch({type: AUTH_USER})
```

which triggers the reducer to update the state

[**/client/src/reducers/auth_reducer.js**](https://github.com/gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth/blob/master/client/src/reducers/auth_reducer.js#L5-L6)

```
export default function authReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case AUTH_USER:
            return {...state, error: '', authenticated: true};
```

**Question:** Why does `{...state, error: '', authenticated: true}` updates `state.auth.authenticated` to `true` instead of updating `state.authenticated` to `true`?

I am guessing `state.auth.authenticated` was updated to `true` because the code below accesses it via `state.auth.authenticated`. Why is this?

[**/client/src/components/auth/signin.js**](https://github.com/gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth/blob/master/client/src/components/auth/signin.js#L48-L50)

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authenticated: state.auth.authenticated,
    errorMessage: state.auth.error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of `combineReducers` in [`index.js`](https://github.com/gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth/blob/master/client/src/reducers/index.js).

When you call `combineReducers`, you combine all your reducers into single one used to construct the store. But every single individual reducer you pass to `combineReducers` governs only *its slice of state*. Thus, since you're passing `authReducer` under the key:

```
auth: authReducer
```

The first argument passed to `authReducer` is `state.auth`. The `authReducer` essentially only governs the `auth` key of state -- its slice of state. So when the `authReducer` returns the new state, it updates its slice, `state.auth`, not just `state` itself. So `state.auth.authenticated` is changed, not `state.authenticated`. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers):

> The state produced by `combineReducers()` namespaces the states of each reducer under their keys as passed to `combineReducers()`

Similarly, the `redux-form` reducer will only ever modify `state.form` because it governs on the `state.form` slice of state as per its key.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `combineReducers` in `index.js` the authReducer has been named `auth` hence the state is accessible as `state.auth.XXX`

Have a look at https://github.com/gillisd/react-router-v4-redux-auth/blob/master/client/src/reducers/index.js